# Java: JApplet, How do you embed it in a webpage?

Tags: java, html, web-applications

I searched for this subject on Google and got some website about an experts exchange...so I figured I should just ask here instead.

How do you embed a `JApplet` in HTML on a webpage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example from [sun's website](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html):

```
<applet code="TumbleItem.class" 
        codebase="examples/"
        archive="tumbleClasses.jar, tumbleImages.jar"
        width="600" height="95">
    <param name="maxwidth" value="120">
    <param name="nimgs" value="17">
    <param name="offset" value="-57">
    <param name="img" value="images/tumble">

Your browser is completely ignoring the &lt;APPLET&gt; tag!
</applet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you didn't say so, just in case you were using JSPs, you also have the option of the [jsp:plugin](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/syntaxref.fm12.html) tag?

Answer (score 1):

Use the <applet> tag.  For more info: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html